# How do I compare attribute to a lower case value?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

How do I create a filter where the attribute value is lowercase?

This works:

```
xmlItem = xml.*.(attribute("name")==propertyName);
```

But this is throwing an error:

```
xmlItem = xml.*.(attribute("name").toLowerCase()==propertyName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I have to use toString() to get the String object and then I can use toLowerCase():

```
var xmlList:XMLList = xml.*.(attribute("name").toString().toLowerCase()==lowerCasePropertyName);
```